# PHP Regex to identify keys in array representation

Tags: php, regex, variables

I have this string `authors[0][system:id]` and I need a regex that returns:

```
array('authors', '0', 'system:id')
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) This is a trivial regex task, please show a little research effort.

Comment: @DaveRandom Yes, I have tried. The closest I can get is this `/([a-z0-9-]+)|(\[(.*)\])*/`. Tested [here](http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php) \_\_Removed frustration words\_\_

Comment: @VladGhita Don't worry, I do understand your frustration, regex is very confusing when you are new to it. Just FYI, please ensure when asking questions that you show what you have tried in the question, the article I linked is well worth a read, it's not chastising you it's simply explaining in quite a nice, useful way how to ask a question which can be easily answer by those who know the answer. I have added an answer below, let me know in comments if there is anything you would like me to explain further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the most simplistic approach, we would just match the three individual parts. So first of all we'd look for the token that is not enclosed in brackets:

```
[a-z]+
```

Then we'd look for the brackets and the value in between:

```
\[[^\]]+\]
```

And then we'd repeat the second step.

You'd also need to add capture groups `()` to extract the actual values that you want.

So when you put it all together you get something like:

```
([a-z]+)\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]]+)\]
```

That expression could then be used with `preg_match()` and the values you want would be extracted into the referenced array passed to the third argument (like [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xEjqEU)). But you'll notice the above expression is quite a difficult-to-read collection of punctuation, and also that the resulting array has an extra element on it that we don't want - `preg_match()` places the whole matched string into the first index of the output array. We're close, but it's not ideal.

However, as @AlienHoboken correctly points out and *almost* correctly implements, a simpler solution would be to split the string up based on the position of the brackets. First let's take a look at the expression we'd need (or at least, the one that I would use):

```
(?:\[|\])+
```

This looks for *at least one occurence* of either `[` or `]` and uses that block as delimiter for the split. This seems like exactly what we need, except when we run it we'll find we have a small issue:

```
array('authors', '0', 'system:id', '')
```

Where did that extra empty string come from? Well, the last character of the input string matches you delimiter expression, so it's treated as a split position - with the result that an empty string gets appended to the results.

This is quite a common issue when splitting based on a regular expression, and luckily PCRE knows this and provides a simple way to avoid it: the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag.

So when we do this:

```
$str = 'authors[0][system:id]';
$expr = '/(?:\[|\])+/';
$result = preg_split($expr, $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($result);
```

...you will see the result you want.

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/K11Ln0)

Comment: It works. Thank you for the explanation. It really helped. Just one more q: Why `?:`?

Comment: @VladGhita `(?:)` is a non-capturing group ([info in the first paragraph](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)). The expression could simply be written as `(\[|\])+`, I guess I just use non-capturing groups in this scenario (when you don't *need* to capture the match) out of force of habit. The expression could also be written as `[\[\]]+`, or even simply `[\[\]]` because of the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag, but I personally prefer a round-bracketed group over a character class when matching square brackets for readability.

Answer (score 3):

Just use PHP's `preg_split()`, which returns an array of elements similarly to `explode()` but with RegEx.

Split the string on `[` or `]` and the remove the last element (which is an empty string) of the provided array, `$tokens`.

EDIT: Also, remove the 3rd element with `array_splice($array, int $offset, int $lenth)`, since this item is also an empty string.

The regex `/[\[\]]/` just means match any `[` or `]` character

```
$string = "authors[0][system:id]";
$tokens = preg_split("/[\]\[]/", $string);
array_pop($tokens);
array_splice($tokens, 2, 1);
//rest of your code using $tokens
```

Here is the format of `$tokens` after this has run:

```
Array ( [0] => authors [1] => 0 [2] => system:id )
```